# Javascript fullscreen closes on changing page

Tags: javascript

I have a button that helps me to open a page in full screen. But when I leave the page the script closes the fullscreen.

Does someone know how I can stay fullscreen when I go to another page?

Here is my full script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function toggleFullScreen() {
    if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||    
      (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {  
      document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();  
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {  
      document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();  
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {  
      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);  
    }  
    } else {  
    if (document.cancelFullScreen) {  
      document.cancelFullScreen();  
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {  
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();  
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {  
      document.webkitCancelFullScreen();  
    }  
    }  
  } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done.
From - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

> In addition, navigating to another page, changing tabs, or switching
>   to another application (using, for example, Alt-Tab) while in
>   fullscreen mode exits fullscreen mode as well.

**Update -**

F11 - makes browser into full screen mode which does not utilize Fullscreen API

Comment: But when I hit F11, my browser goes also to fullscreen. And when I leave the page then the browser stays at fullscreen

Comment: It's quite a different thing to have your installed software go fullscreen when you ask for it compared to some remote html/js controlling when your computer toggles fullscreen. The implications would include things like disguising components to look like the browser UI for phising attacks.